# Calculate the probability of reaching target sum across multiple lotteries

Tags: python

If I have separate lotteries with different prize sizes and different odds of winning, how do I calculate the probability of winning at least a given amount if I play each lottery simultaneously and only once?

- Lottery A: 50% chance of winning 5 gold.
- Lottery B: 40% chance of winning 6 gold.
- Lottery C: 30% chance of winning 7 gold.

Is there a method of calculating the probability that I win at least a given value (like 10 gold) if I play all the lotteries simultaneously? I would ideally like it to work for a set of approximately 40 lotteries.

The input would be a list of tuples with probability and prize size, like:

```
lottery_list = [(0.5, 5), (0.4, 6), (0.3, 7)]
```

And then a function to calculate the probability of winning at least a target value, like in this case 10 gold:

```
prob = win_at_least(lottery_list, target_val=10)
```

Comment: Since you do not specify if there is a cost, I will assume that all lotteries are free. You can then select any lottery and play until you get your desired amount.

Comment: brute force method: you need to find all the possible combinations of the list e.g. ```[A, B, C]``` will give ```[A], [B] ... [A, B], [A, C], [B, C], ... [A, B, C]```  where A is (0.5, 5) etc..
once you have all the possible combinations find all the ones that have a total >= 10 then multiply the probabilities in that group to get the probability for that combination.  then add all the probabilities together that give a total of >=10

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a solution myself. This code ignores combinations that are irrelevant, i.e. all combinations of 'downstream' lotteries if a given set of lotteries has already yielded the target value. It takes about 10 ms for 40 lotteries and seems to scale very well.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def multi_lottery(lottery_list: list, target: float) -> float:
    """
    This function calculates the odds of winning at least the target
    value from a list of lotteries, where each lottery has a
    different probability of winning and a different value.

    Args:
        lottery_list (list): A list of tuples with lottery
            probabilities and values.
        target (float): The target value.

    Returns:
        float: The odds of winning at least target value.
    """
    # Create a pandas dataframe with the lottery list.
    df = pd.DataFrame(lottery_list, columns=["probability", "value"])

    # Sort the dataframe by descending value.
    df_sorted = df.sort_values("value", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)

    probs = df_sorted["probability"].values
    values = df_sorted["value"].values

    # Create a mask equal to the length of the lottery list.
    # This will be used to determine which lotteries are included in
    # each combination.
    length = len(df_sorted)
    mask = np.ones(length, dtype=int)

    # Start with odds of losing at 1.
    total_odds = 0

    while True:
        # Go through the lottery list using the mask to determine if
        # each lottery is won, and add the values together until the target
        # value is reached.
        odds = 1
        value = 0

        for idx, prob in enumerate(probs):
            # Include the winning chance if the binary number is 1.
            if mask[idx] == 1:
                odds *= prob
                value += values[idx]
            # Else include the losing chance.
            else:
                odds *= 1 - prob

            # If the target value is reached, all subsequent lotteries
            # are ignored and the odds are added to the total.
            if value >= target:
                # Update the anti-odds.
                total_odds += odds
                # Update the mask by setting the current lottery to zero.
                mask[idx] = 0
                break

            # Else if the last lottery is reached, update the mask by
            # setting the largest active lottery to zero and all smaller lotteries to one.
            elif idx == length - 1:
                largest_active_idx = 0

                for i, v in enumerate(mask):
                    if v == 1:
                        largest_active_idx = i

                mask[largest_active_idx] = 0
                mask[largest_active_idx + 1 :] = 1

        # Check if the mask is all zeros. If so, break the loop.
        if np.sum(mask) == 0:
            break

    return total_odds
```